# Zend_paginator: changing number of per page elements, when displaying page x (where x>1)?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-paginator

I know, that I can change number of 'per page' elements, when I'm on the first page, but, after I change the page (so there are GET parameters), I'm not able to change number of 'per page' elements.
Am I doing something wrong? Or maybe it isn't possible to do such a thing?

Does anyone has example of this?
Or could anyone tell me, how to achieve this in my code?
[Zend_paginator doesn't change perPage value, when there're some GET parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671019/zend-paginator-doesnt-change-perpage-value-when-therere-some-get-parameters)

Comment: Maybe you could post some code...

Comment: I posted it there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671019/zend-paginator-doesnt-change-perpage-value-when-therere-some-get-parameters

Comment: now I'm just asking, whether this is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

You will always be able (on each request to that action) to change "per page" elements

Comment: Thank You for answer, however... I've never seen working example of this :) Do You know any?

Comment: All you need is here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.usage.html